# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'FLANG Group'

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, neural-network, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to conduct OneHotEncoding on a list of companies in my dataset for the neural network I am building.

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [1])], remainder='passthrough')
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X))
```

And I received this error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/Applications/anaconda3/envs/tenserflowReal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in _hstack(self, Xs)
    630                                             force_all_finite=False)
--> 631                                 for X in Xs]
    632             except ValueError:

/Applications/anaconda3/envs/tenserflowReal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    630                                             force_all_finite=False)
--> 631                                 for X in Xs]
    632             except ValueError:

/Applications/anaconda3/envs/tenserflowReal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     72         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 73         return f(**kwargs)
     74     return inner_f

/Applications/anaconda3/envs/tenserflowReal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    598                 else:
--> 599                     array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    600             except ComplexWarning:

/Applications/anaconda3/envs/tenserflowReal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     84     """
---> 85     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     86 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'FLANG Group'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-86f247aff9da> in <module>
      3 from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
      4 ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [1])], remainder='passthrough')
----> 5 X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X))

/Applications/anaconda3/envs/tenserflowReal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in fit_transform(self, X, y)
    551         self._validate_output(Xs)
    552 
--> 553         return self._hstack(list(Xs))
    554 
    555     def transform(self, X):

/Applications/anaconda3/envs/tenserflowReal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in _hstack(self, Xs)
    631                                 for X in Xs]
    632             except ValueError:
--> 633                 raise ValueError("For a sparse output, all columns should"
    634                                  " be a numeric or convertible to a numeric.")
    635 

ValueError: For a sparse output, all columns should be a numeric or convertible to a numeric.
```

'FLANG Group' is one of the company names which i am trying to OneHotEncode.

what do these error message mean?

Comment: Can you provide your data 'X' or a dummy of it please, so that your error can be reproduced with your code?

Comment: Sure. How do I do that exactly?

Comment: Have a look at the example here https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html, where the code can be run with the data they are providing in one line.

Comment: I actually had some difficulty with creating the reproducible code with a minimal dataset (I am new to coding), so I have opted for creating a link to my mini dataset. I hope this is acceptable and I apologize for any inconvenience this causes. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LGObkzIDFrkWS5A6g4w2PQfa84-6cjj7/view?usp=sharing  X, in this case, is from column 2 (Company name)-second to last column.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with the dataset and it works just fine for me:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

X = pd.read_csv("Updated_Set.csv", sep=';' ) 
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [1])], remainder='passthrough')
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X))
```

Comment: Ahh. Thank you for your efforts. Do you perhaps have any idea why I might be having this problem?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is not with that piece of code but my previous? Please accept this link to my previous piece of code. I am sorry to be a nag on this but I really need the help. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QbOBjp6CFFfSC8za0BQsPHwJaC6JZoXt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: In your code, "X_train" and are "Y_train" undefined. Can you please add the code where you define it as well? Currently I can not run it.

Comment: Oops sorry about that. Kindly ignore those lines of code. Here is the code without that last block of code. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bkQRIQBTfJPPxeQ6MJFg-94c0jaCrRPQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think i know where I went wrong. I put the incorrect index number. It seems to have worked when I entered index 0. Thank you so much for your time and efforts! Much appreciated.